# BigInt is not supported with typestript version 3.5.*

Tags: typescript, npm

If I am understanding correctly, typescript supports BigInt starting version 3.2. My project is on TypeStript 3.5. I am assuming that with this version of typescript, it should support BigInt. Now, I am not declaring any of my variables `BigInt` but I recently installed a package called bufferUtlity: https://github.com/Pharuxtan/BufferUtility#readme

After doing so, my project fails to compile with following error:

`node_modules/bufferutility/index.d.ts(37,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt'.`

I am a little surprised because when I did simple search, I found that it could be an issue for someone who is using a typescript version older than 3.2. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3):

Short version:

1. `bigint` works as a type starting in Typescript 3.2.
2. `BigInt` works as a type starting in Typescript 3.9.
3. The `bufferutility` package uses `BigInt` in its types.

Conclusion: `bufferutility` expects Typescript 3.9 or newer.

---

I can't find the release notes, but `BigInt` does not seem to usable as a type in 3.8 lower.

[See 3.8.3 playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=3.8.3#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3igrgWwC54AhASwHMBJFDIA)

However, starting in 3.9 it works as expected.

[See 3.9.7 Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=3.9.7#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3igrgWwC54AhASwHMBJFDIA)

It looks like [the types for `BufferUtility` use `BigInt` as a type](https://github.com/pharuxtan/BufferUtility/blob/v2/index.d.ts), which probably means the minimum version of typescript you can use here is 3.9.

---

Fun facts about these two types:

```
declare let a: bigint
declare let b: BigInt

b = a // fine. bigint is assignable to BigInt
a = b // Error. Type 'BigInt' is not assignable to type 'bigint'.(2322)
```

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work on TypeScript Playground in `3.8.3`. Checking the Git history, `BigInt` first appears in `3.8-rc` and made it in `3.8.2` ([reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/91ffa1c752ac26882b1426fb4c9012701c1d908e#diff-41dbf20a1e311dfd248a30ab3e2b5acbf2a49393d17d6824dbe955a6b4f9641e)). Testing with a local install of TypeScript at `3.8.2`, your minimal example works as expected.

Comment: The error from the 3.8.3 playground is `Exported variable 'b' has or is using private name 'BigInt'.(4025)`. So it seems it existed but was private? Not sure what that's about.